# Can't compile when including ucontext.h

Tags: c, linux, redhat

Using gcc, I get these errors when compiling something that makes use of ucontext.h

```
    /usr/include/sys/ucontext.h: At top level:
    /usr/include/sys/ucontext.h:138: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before numeric constant
    /usr/include/sys/ucontext.h:139: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘stack_t’
```

Looking at ucontext.h, this is what seems to cause:

```
    134 /* Userlevel context.  */
    135 typedef struct ucontext
    136   {
    137     unsigned long int uc_flags;
    138     struct ucontext *uc_link;
    139     stack_t uc_stack;
    140     mcontext_t uc_mcontext;
    141     __sigset_t uc_sigmask;
    142     struct _libc_fpstate __fpregs_mem;
    143   } ucontext_t;
```

How could line 138 and 139 raise these errors?
Don't know what to do since this is a standard sys header.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have some weird `#define`s in your code somewhere that could break things? grep your code for uc_link.

Comment: Weird enough there's one.

#define uc_link         22

Not sure how that changes things.

Comment: Where is it defined? Is it in your code or elsewhere? Try not to include the file which breaks uc_link, if you can. Frankly... It would be difficult to tell without looking at the code. Anyway, I'm adding a generic answer here. Feel free to add more info, so I can expand and help it.

Comment: The uc_link was in a different header which apparently was being indirectly included since it doesn't raise the errors now. I find this incredible actually.

Comment: Glad to read that. I posted an answer with more clarifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is probably caused by `#define` somewhere in the code, which defines uc_link as some integer.

Example:

```
#define uc_link 22
```

The most efficient way to find it in Unix/Linux would be to run `grep -r "uc_link" .` on your source code directory.
If you use git to manage your source code you can do `git grep "uc_link"` instead.

If this define is present in one file and you use ucontext.h in it, then you should try to decouple your ucontext logic from the logic which demands this `#define`.

Also, I must note that it is a bad practice to have `#define`s which are not ALL_CAPS. One of the reasons is well represented by the problem you encountered, another reason is the fact that everyone expects them to be ALL_CAPS and your code becomes less intelligible and less readable to other programmers who may want to collaborate with you.